# Forward to given URL string

Tags: php, zend-framework

Currently I'm creating a controller (ZendFramework) that gets from database an URL string by given id.

`/linker/show/id/6`

I.e. `id=6` `/products/list/type/games`.

In `LinkerController` I would use `_forward()` method to pass also optional params (POST, GET), but this method takes parameters such like `($action, $controller, $module, $params)` and my string `/products/list/type/games` right now is not valid.

I also do not want to redirect to this URL (user should not see that he is in `ProductController`).

Any ideas how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't forward to URL (because of the nature of forwarding - creating a new internal request object). You can only forward to request (module, controller, action).

Use redirecting insted (in controller):

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrlAndExit($url);
```

Comment: Redirect is not the correct way - as I said, I preffer not to show user a destiny URL.

Comment: then you need to forward to request - not URL. i.e.: module, controller, action, params as you've written above. 

There is NO OTHER WAY. You can't forward to URL (it's no need to, to be honest).

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  You want a mash-up between a redirect and a forward.

Working backwards:

1. You need to call $this->_forward( $action, $controller, $module, $params )
2. So, you need to store these four parameters in your linker table ($params would be serialized)

Then, your linker code might look like:

```
public function showAction()
{
  $linker_table = new LinkerTable();
  $link = $linker_table->find(array('id' => $this->_getParam('id')));

  // first, try to forward, if all settings are there
  if ( $link && $link->hasForwardSettings() ) {
    $this->_forward( $link->action, $link->controller, $link->module, unserialize($link->params));
    return;
  }

  // perhaps other links can just be straight redirects, so then $this->_redirect($link->url)
}
```

Either that or some mod_rewrite magic.

Comment: This way I have to set separatly all of the params: `action, controller and module`.
Is there any way to set only one URL `/products/list/type/games` and explode it to this 3 params ? Any magic ZF method ? ;)